# Logging large messages with node-bunyan-syslog

Tags: node.js, sockets, logging, syslog, bunyan

I'm using [node-bunyan-syslog](https://github.com/mcavage/node-bunyan-syslog) to provide syslog streaming for my node application's Bunyan logger, which seems to be a commonly used library for syslog logging in node applications. Here's my basic logger implementation:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var syslog = require('bunyan-syslog');

var syslogStream = syslog.createBunyanStream({
    host: 'my.remote.host',
    port: 514,
    type: 'udp'
});

module.exports = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'alert-creator-logger',
    streams: [
        {
            level: 'debug',
            type: 'raw',
            stream: syslogStream
        }
    ]
});
```

Every so often, this log statement:

```
logger.debug('Processing message: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

throws the following error:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: send EMSGSIZE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at SendWrap.afterSend [as oncomplete] (dgram.js:348:23)
```

Because my stream is configured to use UDP, I read up on the [UDP(7) spec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html), which indicates that an EMSGSIZE error gets thrown when the size of a packet being transmitted exceeds the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) set for the network interface being used.

My first thought was that the `data` that is being passed into the log statement was too large (and indeed, the error stops being thrown if I only log small messages), as it can sometimes be multiple KB in size. However, shouldn't the size of the log message have nothing to do with the packet size being transmitted by the node-bunyan-syslog stream that I've instantiated?

I looked through the node-bunyan-syslog source code to try to determine if it does its own message decomposition into packets, but I couldn't locate any such logic.

One solution would be to check the size of proposed log messages first and only log if under a certain size, but that seems unnecessarily restrictive. I would expect node-bunyan-syslog or its underlying socket library to handle fundamental protocol limits like MTU without propagating related errors up to the user.

Is my assessment of the cause accurate? Is an EMSGSIZE error in this context caused by exceeding the MTU? How does one successfully log large messages through Bunyan and node-bunyan-syslog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental restriction in the [syslog protocol itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5426#section-3.1).  A single message must be able to fit into a single UDP packet.  And yes, EMSGSIZE means you're exceeding the MTU (with data + protocol overhead).  Bunyan can't really compensate for this as it must speak syslog to syslog servers.

One option is to [switch to tcp](https://github.com/mcavage/node-bunyan-syslog#usage) if your remote syslog server can be configured to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still surprised by the error though, as [RFC-5426](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5426#section-3.1) references [RFC-5424](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#section-6.1), which specifically says that transporters must either discard or truncate oversized messages. Does this mean that node-bunyan-syslog isn't compliant with RFC-5426, given that it errors? Or does an error qualify as a discard? It seems odd that node-bunyan-syslog doesn't simply truncate the message.

Comment: The discard/truncate is a requirement on the receiver side, after the packet is sent.  The originator [should limit the amount of data placed in the packet](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#section-8.3) but the RFC doesn't specify how this is to be done.  So I think node-bunyan-syslog is compliant.  That doesn't mean it's doing the best thing for implementors by not providing better diagnostics or guidance.

Comment: Ah, the receiver! Missed that part. Seems like the best thing to do would be to write a wrapper for it then, such that all of my application's log statements get truncated if necessary. It would be silly to have to check the size of every log statement.

Comment: Does your syslog server not support TCP?

Comment: Not at the moment, though it could be changed. Is it common for syslog servers to use TCP? I figured the lower overhead of UDP was worth using it over TCP for high-load syslog servers.

Answer (score -1):

var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var bsyslog = require('bunyan-syslog');

var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'foo',
    streams: [ {
        level: 'debug',
        type: 'raw',
        stream: bsyslog.createBunyanStream({
            type: 'sys',
            facility: bsyslog.local0,
            host: '192.168.0.1',
            port: 514
        })
    }]
});

log.debug({foo: 'bar'}, 'hello %s', 'world');

That's pretty much it. You create a syslog stream, and point it at a syslog server (UDP by default; you can force TCP by setting type: tcp in the constructor); default is to use facility user and a syslog server on 127.0.0.1:514. Note you must pass type: 'raw' to bunyan in the top-level stream object or this won't work.

If you want your logs to be in the normal bunyan format, rsyslog allows you to setup a template to format it as just the JSON object:

template(name="bunyan" type="string"
         string="%msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:(\{.*\})--end%\n")

local0.* /var/log/application.log;bunyan

You can also write this using the older $template syntax:

$template bunyan,"%msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:({.*})--end%\n"

local0.* /var/log/application.log;bunyan